# Fetch a specific column values from a .txt file with pipe delimiter and load into a new text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with N number of rows and columns, whereas I need to get particular columns with their values and load it into a new text file using batch script, e.g.:

**input.txt**

```
col1|col2|col3.....col71|col72
ew|ds|343.....csdk|gfdf
xc|gh|657.....sdfs|utyy
qw|zx|345.....ffds|xzcz
```

**output.txt**

```
col71|col3
csdk|343
sdfs|657
ffds|345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split text into tokens by (a) certain delimiter(s), use the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). However, this can only handle up to 31 tokens, so you can**not** simply state `tokens=71`, but you can nest multiple loops:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
> "output.txt" (
    rem // Split off the first 31 tokens, pass the rest to the next loop:
    for /F "usebackq delims=| eol=| tokens=3,31*" %%A in ("input.txt") do (
        rem // Split off the next 31 tokens, pass the rest to the next loop:
        for /F "delims=| eol=| tokens=31*" %%D in ("%%C") do (
            rem /* Extract the proper token from the remaining ones (remember
            rem    that 31 + 31 = 62 tokens have been split off before): */
            for /F "delims=| eol=| tokens=9" %%F in ("%%E") do (
                echo(%%F^|%%A
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

If there may be empty columns, the above approach fails, because `for /F` treats consecutive delimiters as one. To overcome this, you could do the following:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
> "output.txt" (
    rem // Read complete lines:
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("input.txt") do (
        rem // Store current line string in interim variable:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Split off the first 31 tokens, pass the rest to the next loop;
        rem    to avoid consecutive delimiters `|`, replace every single one by
        rem    :`"|"`, so `||` becomes `"|""|"`; then enclose the entire result
        rem    within `""`, thus achieving individual tokens enclosed within `""`: */
        for /F "delims=| tokens=3,31*" %%A in (^""!LINE:|="^|"!"^") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Split off the next 31 tokens, pass the rest to the next loop:
            for /F "delims=| tokens=31*" %%D in ("%%C") do (
                rem /* Extract the proper token from the remaining ones (remember
                rem    that 31 + 31 = 62 tokens have been split off before): */
                for /F "delims=| tokens=9" %%F in ("%%E") do (
                    rem // Remove the previously added surrounding `""` by `~`:
                    echo(%%~F^|%%~A
                )
            )
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
```

This approach will still fail if there are already quoted field values that contain `|` on their own.

Comment: Hi aschipfl, thank you for the solution but i need one clarification, using this token split i can able to fetch the token values of 31st column(echo %%~A), 62nd column(echo %%~C) , 72 column(echo %%~E) but i need to fetch 27 columns from these 72 columns i have is there any way to fetch the column values between 1-31 ,31-62, 62-72 will be grateful.. thanks and regards, JJ

Comment: In both of my scripts, `%%A` receives the 3rd token, `%%B` receives the 31st one and `%%C` receives the rest (`tokens=3,31*` defines 3 tokens: `3`, `31`, `*`); so I start with `%%D` for the next loop. Hence if you need more tokens, just state them in the `tokens=` options (in ascending order) and make sure the letters for the nested loops do not overlap. If you are running out of letters, specify small ones (`for` treats its variable references case-sensitively, so `%%A` is different from `%%a`). See also the help of `for /?`...

Answer (score 0):

### Linux

You could use `awk -F "|" '{ print $70 "|" $2 }' input.txt > output.txt`.

Usually one would probably execute `cut -d"|" -f2,70 input.txt > output.txt`, the only problem is that `cut` (as far as I know) doesn't support reordering columns.

### Powershell

On Windows' powershell (also available for Linux) you can use the following snippet:

```
Get-Content 'input.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $array = $_.split("|")
  $array[70] + '|' + $array[2]
} | Out-File 'output.txt'
```

Comment: just a note: on windows, consecutive delimiters are treated as one, so the Windows solution fails / give false results, if there are empty columns.

Comment: I'm afraid the Windows version won't work, because `for /F` cannot handle more than 31 tokens...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it to a powershell snippets, which would automatically solve both issues.

Answer (score 0):

The following Batch file is a general-purpose program that use a series of nested `FOR /F` commands that allows access to up to 177 tokens, but in a very simple way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Method to use up to 177 tokens in a FOR /F command in a simple way
rem Antonio Perez Ayala


rem Create an example file with lines with 180 tokens each
(for %%a in (A B C) do (
   set "line="
   for /L %%i in (1,1,180) do set "line=!line! %%a%%i"
   echo !line!
)) > test.txt
set "line="


rem Load the string of tokens characters from FOR-FcharsCP850.txt file
chcp 850 > NUL
if exist FOR-FcharsCP850.txt goto readChars
echo Creating FOR-F characters file, please wait...
set "options=/d compress=off /d reserveperdatablocksize=26"
type nul > t.tmp

> FOR-FcharsCP850.txt (
set /P "=0" < NUL

rem Create 87 characters in 38..124 range for 3 FOR's with "tokens=1-28*"
set "i=0"
for /L %%i in (38,1,124) do (
   set /A i+=1, mod=i%%29
   if !mod! neq 0 (
      call :genchr %%i
      type %%i.chr
      del %%i.chr
   )
)

rem Create 95 characters for 3 FOR's with "tokens=1-31*"
rem This is the tokens sequence used when code page = 850
set "i=0"
for %%i in (173 189 156 207 190 221 245 249 184 166 174 170 240 169 238 248
            241 253 252 239 230 244 250 247 251 167 175 172 171 243 168 183
            181 182 199 142 143 146 128 212 144 210 211 222 214 215 216 209
            165 227 224 226 229 153 158 157 235 233 234 154 237 232 225 133
            160 131 198 132 134 145 135 138 130 136 137 141 161 140 139 208
            164 149 162 147 228 148 246 155 151 163 150 129 236 231 152    ) do (
   set /A i+=1, mod=i%%32
   if !mod! neq 0 (
      call :genchr %%i
      type %%i.chr
      del %%i.chr
   )
))
del t.tmp temp.tmp
set "options="
:readChars
set /P "char=" < FOR-FcharsCP850.txt
set "lastToken=177"


cls
echo Enter tokens definition string in the same way of FOR /F "tokens=x,y,m-n" one
echo/
echo You may define a tokens range in descending order: "tokens=10-6" = 10 9 8 7 6
echo or add an increment different than 1: "tokens=10-35+5" = 10 15 20 25 30 35
echo Combine them: "tokens=10,28-32,170-161-3" = 10 28 29 30 31 32 170 167 164 161
echo/
echo The maximum token number is 177

:nextSet
echo/
set /P "tokens=tokens="
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

rem Expand the given tokens string into a series of individual FOR tokens values 
set "tokensValues="
for %%t in (%tokens%) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-+" %%i in ("%%t") do (
      if "%%j" equ "" (
         if %%i leq %lastToken% set "tokensValues=!tokensValues! %%!char:~%%i,1!"
      ) else (
         if "%%k" equ "" (set "k=1") else set "k=%%k"
         if %%i gtr %%j set "k=-!k!"
         for /L %%n in (%%i,!k!,%%j) do if %%n leq %lastToken% set "tokensValues=!tokensValues! %%!char:~%%n,1!"
      )
   )
)

rem First three FOR's use as tokens the ASCII chars in 38..124 (&..|) range: 28*3 = 84 tokens + 3 tokens for next FOR
rem Next three FOR's use as tokens Extended chars: 31*3 = 93 tokens + 2 tokens for next FOR
rem based on the tokens sequence used when code page = 850
rem Total: 177 tokens

for /F "eol= tokens=1-28*" %%^& in (test.txt) do ^
for /F "eol= tokens=1-28*" %%C in ("%%B") do ^
for /F "eol= tokens=1-28*" %%` in ("%%_") do ^
for /F "eol= tokens=1-31*" %%­ in ("%%|") do ^
for /F "eol= tokens=1-31*" %%µ in ("%%·") do ^
for /F "eol= tokens=1-31"  %%  in ("%%…") do (
   call :getTokens result=
   rem Process here the "result" string:
   echo !result!
)
goto nextSet


:getTokens result=
for %%# in (-) do set "%1=%tokensValues%"
exit /B


REM This code creates one single byte. Parameter: int
REM Teamwork of carlos, penpen, aGerman, dbenham
REM Tested under Win2000, XP, Win7, Win8
:genchr
if %~1 neq 26 (
   makecab %options% /d reserveperfoldersize=%~1 t.tmp %~1.chr > nul
   type %~1.chr | ( (for /l %%N in (1,1,38) do pause)>nul & findstr "^" > temp.tmp )
   >nul copy /y temp.tmp /a %~1.chr /b
) else (
   copy /y nul + nul /a 26.chr /a >nul
)
goto :eof
```

**IMPORTANT**: The series of six nested `FOR /F` commands use the following ASCII characters in the replaceable parameter and the character between quotes:

> for /F "eol= tokens=1-28*" %%^& in (test.txt) do ^      %%^38
>
> for /F "eol= tokens=1-28*" %%C in ("%%B") do ^          %%67  in ("66")
>
> for /F "eol= tokens=1-28*" %%` in ("%%_") do ^          %%96  in ("95")
>
> for /F "eol= tokens=1-31*" %%­ in ("%%|") do ^          %%173 in ("124")
>
> for /F "eol= tokens=1-31*" %%µ in ("%%·") do ^          %%181 in ("183")
>
> for /F "eol= tokens=1-31"  %%  in ("%%…") do (          %%160 in ("133")

However, it seems that some web browser don't correctly copy-paste some extended characters. If the program don't works correctly, you should check that these characters were correctly copied and fix they if necessary. You may try to copy the lines above (in pink background) and test if they were correctly copied...

Output example:

```
Enter tokens definition string in the same way of FOR /F "tokens=x,y,m-n" one

You may define a tokens range in descending order: "tokens=10-6" = 10 9 8 7 6
or add an increment different than 1: "tokens=10-35+5" = 10 15 20 25 30 35
Combine them: "tokens=10,28-32,170-161-3" = 10 28 29 30 31 32 170 167 164 161

The maximum token number is 177

tokens=10-6
 A10 A9 A8 A7 A6
 B10 B9 B8 B7 B6
 C10 C9 C8 C7 C6

tokens=10-35+5
 A10 A15 A20 A25 A30 A35
 B10 B15 B20 B25 B30 B35
 C10 C15 C20 C25 C30 C35

tokens=10,28-32,170-161-3
 A10 A28 A29 A30 A31 A32 A170 A167 A164 A161
 B10 B28 B29 B30 B31 B32 B170 B167 B164 B161
 C10 C28 C29 C30 C31 C32 C170 C167 C164 C161

tokens=71,3
 A71 A3
 B71 B3
 C71 C3
```

If your application requires less than 177 tokens, you may modify this program and eliminate the code sections of the not required tokens; that is, with 2 `FOR`'s you may access up to 56 tokens, with 3 up to 84, with 4 up to 115, and with 5 up to 146.

You may review a detailed explanation of this method [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703); you may also download (a previous version of) this program in a .zip file from [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703&p=51249#p51249) that would allow to fix the problem of the extended characters in the six `FOR /F` commands in a simple way...